# Buttons in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My button creates text in one line. So if I click it multiple times it will just display the text in one long line. I have come to ask if there is a way to replace the text created by the click when you press the button again. so that every time you press the button, it doesn't just add it to one long line, but instead displays only the text from that click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.innerHTML` to replace elements within a DOM object.

```js
function ReplaceText(){
  document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "My new text";
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="mytext">
      My text
    </div>

    <button id="replace" onclick="ReplaceText()"> Replace Text </button>

  </body>

</html>
```